# Subclass UINavigationbar for customise in iOS7 does not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have made a subclass of the navigation bar.
In there I set a background image and I would like to disable the clipping, because my Image has some shadow and an arrow which is higher than the navigation bar.

in iOS 6&5 it works perfectly when I remove the tick Clip Subviews in the Interface Builder in Xcode.
In iOS7 unfortunately the background image is always clipped...
I also tried to add the following lines:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tt_navigation_bar.png"];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tt_navigation_bar-ios7.png"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:21.0], UITextAttributeFont, [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:109.0/255.0 blue:36.0/255.0 alpha:1], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];

    for (UIView *v in [self subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"v: %@", v);
        v.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    }
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
}
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually editing my two images into the top n pixels and then "the rest" and setting the image of "the rest" to the `shadowImage`.